# DisplayLink provider does not show up with USBC Lenovo dock

Tags: arch-linux, thinkpad, displaylink

Trying to run two screens connected to a ThinkPad USBC dock, which is connected to my laptop via USBC. The dock is connected as it charges and works with external mouse / keyboard.

I have followed the instructions to the letter on DisplayLink section of the arch wiki.

When running `xrandr --listproviders`, only one provider shows up. The displaylink provider does not show up:

`Providers: number : 1 Provider 0: id: 0x48 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 6 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting`

I have tried all versions of evdi (evdi, evdi-git, evdi-compat-git). udl is installed and running and I have edited the 20-evdi.conf file. I have updated my system, re installed displaylink, all versions of evdi, etc. I have tried any debugging solutions I can find.

Comment: Are you sure it has DisplayLink? Many USB-C docks expect USB-C alternative mode for video or thunderbolt - support dependent on the laptop - and not the old DisplayLink "virtual" screen chipset. The fact that you mention 2 (two) screens suggests the former because DisplayLink typically provide only one output.

Comment: You're right - it does not have DisplayLink. I'm using thunderbolt, which is another issue. If anyone comes across this in the future, I have not solved it but you can see details on a similar issue here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=285470